# How to configure RabbitMQ server cluster and what are the benefits?

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq

I am currently working on single RabbitMQ server which support 20000 to 25672 TCP connection. So is it possible to expand the 
TCP connection limit using RabbitMQ server cluster, If yes then How can to configure it and what are the benefits?

Comment: Could you indicate how many channels you have per connection?

Comment: one connection per one channel (Queue)

Comment: TCP connections are often limited also by the underlying OS. You would need to investigate the platform-specific configuration of your host.

Comment: I should add that, while RMQ can *theoretically* handle many thousands of connections, the practical implications of this situation are that you have improperly designed your application architecture.

Answer (score 0):

With the cluster, you can handle a lot of connections since the connections can be shared across more machines.

To configure the cluster you can follow the official documentation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

```
rabbit2$ rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping node rabbit@rabbit2 ...done.
rabbit2$ rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1
Clustering node rabbit@rabbit2 with [rabbit@rabbit1] ...done.
rabbit2$ rabbitmqctl start_app
Starting node rabbit@rabbit2 ...done.
```

Comment: Thanks #gabriele, but i also want to know some core benefits of RabbitMQ Server clustering.